# Exit application with back button

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an application that uses bluetooth and need to exit the bluetooth connection on exit and back button. I have setup a Exit button that works fine with a Finish() and System.exit(0) but need to use this same method with the back button. I have read several threads that the exit button is not advised. I am looking for further comments on this practice.

```
      BtnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });
```

I have added OnDestroy and OnStop which takes care of both back button and home press button. I chose to just kill application instead of just shutting down the bluetooth connection.

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    finish();
    System.exit(0);


}
```

Comment: just to let you know that closing the application yourself this way is a bad thing. You should let the system close the application itself. Going the way you're closing your application just make ignore the Activity lifecycle (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override one of the functions of the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Since you want to close a connection I think it is best to override the `onDestroy();` method, which will be called when the App is either explicitly removed from memory or removed to make room for other processes.

If you would like to close the connection when the `Activity` is no longer visible you could override `onStop` instead of `onDestroy`

```
@override
public void onDestroy(){
    //your bluetooth disconnection code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use...

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to override onBackPressed().
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()